# Finding matrix of a linear transformation using R programing

Tags: r, linear-algebra

The full question is:
Let {u1, u2,···, un} and {x1, x2,···, xm} be bases for Rn and Rm respectively. Let T:Rn→Rm be the linear transformation whose associated matrix with respect to the above bases is A. Write a program in R such that given two sets of vectors{v1, v2,···, vn} and {w1, w2,···, wm}examines whether these two sets form basis for Rn and Rm respectively, and if so computes the new matrix which represents T with respect to the new bases

I am new to both R programing and linear algebra. I only know the basics of linear transformation. I do not understand how I can find the matrix representation since The function T is not defined. I also cannot understand how to take the input for the basis itself. Please help me understand how I can start with the program. Also, this is my first question so if you need any extra information or anything that I can provide please let me know.

```
basis=c("v1","v2","v3")
v1=c(1,2,3)
v2=c(4,3,2)
v3=c(9,4,6)
d=rbind(v1,v2,v3)
x=matrix(c(0,0,0), byrow=0)
solve(d,x)

     [,1]
[1,]    0
[2,]    0
[3,]    0
```

Is this how I can show that the vectors v1,v2,v3 are linearly independent?
How can I show that they span the vector space?

Comment: It is typical (but not necessary) for the basis vectors to be stored as _columns_, so I might do `X <- cbind(v1, v2, v3)`. You could use any of `determinant(X)$modulus`, `eigen(X)$values`, and `qr(X)$rank` to test for linear independence of `v1`, `v2`, and `v3`, within some numerical tolerance. You should review the corresponding help pages (with `?determinant`, etc.), and maybe also the Wikipedia entry on invertibility ([here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Invertible_matrix)).

Comment: @MikaelJagan thank you, for basis after linear independence i will need to check if it is a spanning set as well, will finding the rank of the corresponding matrix be enough?

Comment: `t()` is implemented, however.

Comment: @MikaelJagan X=cbind(v1,v2,v3)
qr(X)$rank [rank will help me understand if it is linearly independent]
det(X) [this will help me understand if it spans or not]
But I cannot understand how to takes these values as user input. 
since the values of n and m are not fixed they have to be taken by the user, after that, we also need the value of the vectors that form the basis, I cannot understand how to go about that.